# AngularJs missing the obvious

Tags: angularjs

Newbie to Angular and missing something very obvious.  All I am trying to do is route a link.
Main Page

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
 <title></title>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <script src="../Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/angular-route.min.js"></script>
 
 <script src="../Scripts/application/angular-module.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="navController">
        <a href="/engagement">engagement</a>
        {{message}}
    </div>
 <div ng-view></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Child Page

```html
<div ng-controller="engagementController">
    Engagements
</div>
```

And the module

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute'])
    .config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/engagement', { templateUrl: 'Pages/Engagement.html' });
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);


    })
    .controller('navController', 'NavController')
    .controller('engagementController', 'EngagementController');

function NavController($scope) {
    $scope.message = "Main Page";
}

function EngagementController($scope) {
    $scope.message = "Engagement Page";
};
```

What happens:
when I click the engagement link, I am directed to localhost/engagement and get a 404.  It does not appear to properly handle the routing instruction.

File locations: Main.html is a root, Engagement.html is in a Pages subdirectory.

Comment: did you configure server to use angular html5mode? Important to recognize server side routing implications when not using hash in url

Comment: I believe that should be `<a href="engagement">engagement</a>`; without the leading forward slash.

Answer (score 0):

First of all define first route also with the url of root /

and check the url of template is it ok or folder is correctly define

then define the  engagement

it will work i am sure

Answer (score 0):

Use you app.js to define different states ie. the different pages your app will have.

then in your controller (on the button click) you need to add the line

```
$state.go('engagement');
```

to change the state to the correct page when you press the button.